# How to search the text for several lines and find in order using regular expression

Tags: notepad++, regex

Trying to figure out the regular expression to be used in Notepad++ where I can search the text below (as an example) and find the results in order.

Sample Text:

```
{ USERECOVERDB 1 }

protocol to_nuance_orm_p5 {
{ AUTOSTART 1 }
{ DELAYCONNECT 0 }
{ HOST 198.92.118.168 }
{ IPV4_V6_DUAL 0 }
{ PDLTYPE tcp-client }
{ PORT 9014 }
{ PRIVATE_KEY {} }
```

Desired result:

```
protocol to_nuance_orm_p5
HOST 198.92.118.168
PORT 9014
```

Comment: Please look at the preview before posting and use [formatting](https://superuser.com/help/formatting), your question was completely unreadable before @snowdude fixed it.

Comment: Are those asterisks actually in your text or is it your formatting?

Comment: No, the asterisks are not in my code.  I had it the way I did on purpose. I'll clean it up to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex should work:

```
protocol [^ ]+|HOST \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|PORT \d+
```

I'm using Sublime Text to test it, but it should work in Notepad++ too.

Here's how it works: it's composed from three parts:

- `protocol [^ ]+`
- `HOST \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`
- `PORT \d+`

`|` symbol means that any of those parts can be matched.

**First part:** `protocol [^ ]+`

`protocol` (including the space after `l`) simply matches the word `protocol` and following space. `[^ ]` matches one non-space character and `+` means to match one or more preceding symbols, so `[^ ]+` will match one or more non-space symbols.

**Second part:** `HOST \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`

`HOST` matches text just like in the first part. Then there's `\d` which matches one digit and `+` which has the same meaning as above. `\.` will match regular dots. Unlike with letters, a dot has to be preceded with a backslash, because it has a special meaning in regular expressions.

**Third part** is even simplier than the second one, so I don't think explainations are necessary.

If you want to learn more about regular expressions, [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is quite good and [here's a good regex tester/debugger](https://www.debuggex.com/).

Comment: You should be experienced enough to know that such one-liners are frowned upon, in this site. Please explain, albeit briefly, why this is supposed to work.

Comment: WOAH! Now that is slick!!! Looks beautiful! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find all text in the format:

```
** TEXT **
```

try this:

```
\*\*.*\*\*
```